# How to add a context-menu on single click in Tabulator cell?

Tags: contextmenu, tabulator

I need to implement a context menu in Tabulator on a single click of a cell that has an icon in it. Currently tabulator has a default context menu on right clicks of table cells. Is there any way to implement it on one single tap?

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is not built in at present, If you would like to see the functionality added to the library please create a Feature Request